# use underscore.js list functions on collection of jquery objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I'm am working with an app that uses both jQuery and underscore.js . I'd like to be able to use some of underscore's iterator functions, such as `any()` and `all()` over a collection of jQuery objects. is there a way to do this? I'd like to do something similar to the following:

```
checkboxes = $("input[type=checkbox]");
_.filter(checkboxes, function(box) {
    return box.is(":checked");
});
```

but this throws an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLInputElement> has no method 'is'
```

so I'm assuming box in this context isn't acting like as a jQuery object.

Comment: is there a reason for not just doing `$("input[type=checkbox]:checked")` ?

Comment: i could do that in this case, but I was asking about all of the underscore interation methods in general, including _.any(), _.all(), etc.

Comment: You very rarely need jQuery when handling one element at a time, for example you could have just done `return box.checked`;

Comment: Just some semantic clarifications: `checkboxes` here is not a "collection of jQuery objects", it's a single jQuery object. But of course every jQuery object is a collection whether it contains 0, 1, or many items.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to wrap `box` in jQuery:

```
checkboxes = $("input[type=checkbox]");
checkboxes = _.filter(checkboxes, function(box) {
    return $(box).is(":checked");
});
```

---

Also, instead of creating a new object for every single element in the collection, you could just use the native `box.checked`:

```
checkboxes = $("input[type=checkbox]");
checkboxes = _.filter(checkboxes, function(box) {
    return box.checked;
});
```

**On a side note:** [jQuery has its own filter method](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
checkboxes = $("input[type=checkbox]").filter(function() {
    return $(this).is(":checked");
});
```

---

Furthermore, in your example - are you sure you have to filter? You could just as easily use that as your selector:

```
checkboxes = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked")
```

Comment: filter was just an example. I also thought of using _.any , _.all, and  such for some situations.

Comment: @Joseph, thanks - this helped me out. Could you please explain why `You have to wrap box in jQuery`?

Comment: @KevinMeredith - whenever you iterate over a jQuery collection, the individual items with it are simple vanilla DOM elements. If you want to get the jQuery functionality, you have to create a new jQuery instance.

Answer (score 1):

Here `box` is a `HTMLInputElement` type object. Its not a jQuery object. As [`.is`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) is a jQuery object method, you need jQuery object from `box`.

It can be just done by, `$(box)`. Then apply `.is()`.

```
$(box).is(":checked");
```